# Show Cron expression as text in Hangfire Dashboard in mvc core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, hangfire

Q1- I used Hangfire Dashboard in ASP.NET MVC Core 2.2, but I need to show a cron expression in "Recurring Job" as Text.

Example:  when cron value is * * * * *  show text in table is  "Every minute"

```
       when cron value is 0 8 * * *   show text in table is "At 08:00"
```

And so on ...... as show in attachment image

Q2- Can I edit on Hangfire Dashboard code or do I have access to Hangfire Dashboard code and edit it as HTML?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute [DisplayName("...")] on the method you hand over to HangFire as your job. The text given to DisplayName is then shown on the HangFire dashboard

Comment: I've tested and tried to do this on a a project that the Dashbaord does not have assemblies. Instead of DisplayName working, i only get 'Could not find target method'. Does the Dashboard HAVE to have the assembly reference in order to override in order for the DisplayName attribute to work ?